# v-tooltip showing anywhere on screen. Not showing next to the v-icon after scrolling

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify version 2.3.10. The issue I am facing here is that the tooltip messages for the secong container shows any where on the screen rather than showing next to tooltip icon. For the first container it shows next to the icon. Please help me find where I am going wrong. Below is my code.

```
<template>
    <v-card class="mb-12">
      <v-form :model='user'>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right tip-align">
              <v-text-field
                      label='Name'
                      v-model='user.name'>
              </v-text-field>
              <v-tooltip attach=".tip-align" left>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                  <span v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"><v-icon class="icon-align" small slot="activator" dark color="primary">info</v-icon></span>
                </template>
                <span>Please enter name.</span>
              </v-tooltip>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-left tip-align">
              <v-text-field
                      label='Address'
                      v-model='user.address'>
              </v-text-field>
              <v-tooltip attach=".tip-align" left>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                  <span v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"><v-icon class="icon-align" small slot="activator" dark color="primary">info</v-icon></span>
                </template>
                <span>Please enter your address</span>
              </v-tooltip>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right tip-align">
              <v-text-field
                      label='Position'
                      v-model='user.position'>
              </v-text-field>
              <v-tooltip attach=".tip-align" left>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                  <span v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"><v-icon class="icon-align" small slot="activator" dark color="primary">info</v-icon></span>
                </template>
                <span>Please enter position.</span>
              </v-tooltip>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-left tip-align">
              <v-text-field
                      label='Number'
                      v-model='user.number'>
              </v-text-field>
              <v-tooltip attach=".tip-align" left>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                  <span v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"><v-icon class="icon-align" small slot="activator" dark color="primary">info</v-icon></span>
                </template>
                <span>Please enter your number</span>
              </v-tooltip>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-form>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this issue on small screen where you need to scroll the content of the card. It might have something to do with your `<v-tooltip attach=".tip-align"/>` that attempts to attach the element that has a class of `.tip-align`. However, there are 4 elements (the `<v-flex/>` elements) that have the class of `.tip-align` and there might be a problem with that.

You can just remove the `attach=".tip-align"` prop since it will be attached to the default slot by default (to your `<v-icon/>` elements in your case).

P.S. If you're using Vuetify 2.x, you can improve your layout using `<v-row/>` and `<v-col/>`.

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-cannon-9ldk2?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).

Comment: I tried what you suggest, I am still facing the issue. I have removed attach prop and improved the layout with v-row and v-col. For the fields that appear on screen after scrolling, for them tooltip is still not aligned. It still shows on top of the page rather than being aligned with the v-icon

Comment: It might have something to do with your other styles then. Can you create a fiddle or a demo at codesandbox so we can look into the problem better?

Comment: There is some issue on my end. I created a sandbox and it works fine there.

Comment: The issue which I am facing is something like this 
http://jsfiddle.net/kuzxLwxe/4/

Comment: If it works on codesandbox, there's probably some outside style that affects the placement of the tooltips